# How to implement Facebook or Twitter login in Blackberry Playbook Application

Tags: html, emulation, blackberry-playbook, facebook-login

I have been working with development of Blackberry Playbook Application, i.e.. HTML5/Webworks, I would like to implement a feature of Facebook Login for my application, but for some reasons I couldn't do that.

For testing I have been using Ripple Emulator

Code for facebook login button -

Button - Facebook Developers

I have added this code just below the body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

With this code I am able to see the login button, but when I click on the button it does not generate the popup like we get on web application.

Please suggest any ideas for the same.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=**APP_ID**";
```

APP_ID is your app_id, you've got to replace it.